# yield doesn't work in section Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the site with the structure like:

First: `master.blade.php` : this contain `section('content')`

```
<body>
   @include('partial.header')
   @yield('content')
   @include('partial.footer')
</body>
```

Second `index.blade.php` : contain `section('content')`.

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div id="container">
   <div id="news">
      @yield('news')
   </div>
   <div id="apartment">
      @yield('apartment')
   </div>
</div> <!-- ./container -->
@endsection
```

Third: `news.blade.php` : this simple to show all `news`

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
@endforeach
```

Final file: `apartment.blade.php` : this simple to show all `apartment`.

```
@foreach($apartments as $apartment)
@endforeach
```

My route direct to `master.blade.php`.
My question is:

1. When I include `news` with `@yield('news')` in `index.blade.php`. It shows correct all `news` in my database.
   But when I delete `@yield('news')` in `index.blade.php`. It also show `news` from my database (but it's lost css/js for that).
   Why I deleted `@yield('news')`, it's should don't show any `news` on my page?
2. Seem Laravel Blade not support two `@yield` in `@section`. When I add only 1 row `@yield('news')` into `index.blade.php` file. It shows list news on my index page. When I continues add `@yield('apartment')`. Don't have any apartment shown on the index page. I certainly it has values when `foreach` to get data. I also test with HTML statics but don't have anything changes.

Comment: Its not yeild if you want to add other template use include to include partial templates

Comment: Is your mind like: `@include('news')`?

Comment: Yes. Thats how you include. Or you can search for including templates in laravel if that doesn't work

Comment: @Exprator It's the same result.

Answer (score 0):

> My route direct to master.blade.php.

Index extends master, so point your route to index view.

If sections continue to be yielded, after @yield removal, I think the framework is loading a cached view.

Try clearing the view cache `php artisan view:clear` or use `php artisan --help view:clear` for help.

Also @yield yields a section in a parent child relationship.

Change yields to include like `@include('partial.news')` if news are in partial folder or to whatever the path. Rendering could be manipulated using `@isset` or `@empty` statements or even `@forelse` loops.

[Blade Control Structures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#control-structures).